Take table backup of size more that 4 TB before trucnate
I have an existing table which is more that 4 TB in out 19C Oracle DB. This is Oracle ERP table which maintains history. Oracle agreed that we can delete this data.
But due to Sox issue - we want to preserve the data.
Take backup of this table it taking more than 30 hour.
Is there any faster way to take the Table backup or move data to new table or take a take a dump in Unix.  And in worst scenario recover the data.


... table ... more that 4 TB ... Oracle ERP table which maintains history.
Oracle agreed that we can delete this data.


But due to Sox issue - we want to preserve the data.

You have conflicting Requirements here.
Clearly you consider 4TB of history to be excessive but Sox requires to keep that history.
Short answer: SOX wins.
Failure to have Sox compliance could "cost" your company a lot more than the price of the additional disks needed to hold this data.
Having a big table in Oracle isn't generally a problem.  It will spend most of its time sitting, quietly, on disk in a Data File, at least until you want to query it.
There is, of course, the question of whether you need all of that 4TB of history.
That would depend on your Requirements for examining that history.  It might be that you can reduce it to a defined "window" of history and "nibble" away at the end of it to keep it in check.

If I had a task of backup/restore of big table here are my thoughts

30 hours of backup is not a concern
30 hours of restoring is way worse, plus add time for retrieving the export file
so I'd rename the table and put it on separate read-only tablespace
now we can export it via transportable tablespace feature.
restoring is retrieving datafiles and import the transportable tablespace


This table is part of Oracle ERP package. If I rename for some moment - objects will become invalid

Recompile invalid objects.

You can rename it and create a new table with the old name. Once that's done, it won't matter how long the dump takes.

This table is part of Oracle ERP package. If I rename for some moment - objects will become invalid. Oracle will not allow to do this.

Well, if you take directions from Oracle, ask them how to do what you want.
